# Is anything written after iostream allowed in c++

Tags: c++, iostream, turbo-c++

In C++ program instead of `iostream.h` if I write `iostreamhihiju.h` it still works. It does not give an error. Like this:

[image]

Anything written after `iostream` is allowed, can someone help to find the the reason?

Comment: Looks like you have created `iostreamhello.h` and included `iostream.h` in it!

Comment: iostream.h is not a part of C++ for some 20 years. You need to update your tools and reading material.

Comment: I never thought anyone still was this ancient

Comment: Can you please remove the picture and copy the text here!

Comment: @Klaus Note that in this case, the picture turned out to provide additional information that the text wouldn't have. Adding the text is fine, but the picture shouldn't be removed unless all relevant information is provided in text form.

Comment: The picture shows she's using an ancient compiler, which provides a lot of context.

Answer (score 4):

You appear to be using an ancient DOS-based compiler. In DOS, file names can have at most 8 characters before the extension, anything more is silently dropped. `iostream.h`, `iostreamx.h` and `iostreamhihiju.h` all name the same file.

This will stop working when you move to a Windows-based compiler.

Comment: ...   or a unix based compiler, or a compiler written for any system that is not limited to 8 characters in a filename .....   i.e.   most compilers since the mid 90s, other than a couple that target obscure embedded systems.

Comment: @Peter The OP is already using Windows, that is why I stuck with Windows.